# How to find out what a cstyle cast actually does?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, casting

I'm working with a codebase that is quite old and has a lot of c-style casts.

I know what a c-style cast can do but how do I quickly find out what a line of code like this does:

```
WhateverClass* oldD = (WhateverClass*)d->GetHandle();
```

I know I can go through the code, find out what `GetHandle()` returns, determine how is it related to `WhateverClass` and then reason about which of the five possible outcomes of c-style cast applies here.

Still I am a human prone to errors and I'd much prefer a definitive answer free of my reasoning.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 but I'm also interested to hear about other IDEs and compilers.

Comment: Good luck! That's exctly the reason why the new, expressive cast operators were created. Thy old C-style casting just sucks...

Answer (score 1):

Use [clang-tidy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/clang-tidy?view=msvc-160) - this check [cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-cstyle-cast](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-cstyle-cast.html) flags c-style casts that performs any of those:

- static_cast
- downcast
- const_cast
- reinterpret_cast

More can be read from its [source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/master/clang-tidy/cppcoreguidelines/ProTypeCstyleCastCheck.cpp). It seems the diagnostic is pretty accurate and with "-fix" option you might try auto-fixing.

There is also [google-readability-casting](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/google-readability-casting.html) from the same clang-tidy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know about clang-tidy, this has two problems however:
1) the code has to be compileable with clang - a huge task in my case (MFC application with 3M lines of code developed in Visual Studio)
2) clang-tidy warns about cstyle cast usage (which is admittedly useful) but AFAIK it does not tell you exactly what cast is used anyway

Comment: For the second reason - you might be right. But - see source - it can be "modified". In line 48 you might put the information what kind of cast it is - see `MatchedCast->getCastKind() `. Changing and recompiling clang-tidy is not a big effort comparing to 3M codebase. For the first - have you tried to use some other switches  - like `-std=C++03`. Or just for this "experiment" - stub some of your code with clang-compatible replacement. I'd go in this direction or try to search for another static analysis tools - like CppCheck?

Comment: It's not that simple with getCastKind() - the result does not map straightforwardly to static/const/reinterpret cast. Other switches won't help as we are using some c++11 code already. Stubbing some of the code is not a viable option. I'll upvote your answer because some people might find it useful but it does not answer the question unfortunately.